# URL с www и без www

Tags: java

делаю так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
InetAddress adr;

adr = InetAddress.getByName("www.mail.ru");
System.out.println(adr);
System.out.println();

InetAddress SW[] = InetAddress.getAllByName("www.mail.ru");
for (InetAddress ia : SW) 
    System.out.println(ia);
    System.out.println();

adr = InetAddress.getByName("mail.ru");
System.out.println(adr);
System.out.println();

SW = InetAddress.getAllByName("mail.ru");
for (InetAddress ia : SW) 
    System.out.println(ia);
}
```

вывод такой:

```
www.mail.ru/217.69.139.70

www.mail.ru/217.69.139.70
www.mail.ru/94.100.180.70

mail.ru/94.100.180.202

mail.ru/94.100.180.202
mail.ru/217.69.139.200
mail.ru/217.69.139.202
mail.ru/94.100.180.200
```

Вопросы:
1. Чем отличается адрес с www и без? Это что, 2 абсолютно разных сервера? И что, тогда получается одинаковые страницы mail.ru находятся на 6 разных серверах? Или страница в одном экземпляре, просто на нее перенаправляются все запросы.
2. Почему в 1 и 4 строчках именно эти адреса. Из каких соображения jvm их выбрала. Случайным образом или в порядке приоритета или еще чего?

Comment: mail.ru все что угодно может отмочить :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Формально, это два разных адреса. По сути, можно сказать, что www - это поддмомен, если грубо. Разные A record в DNS записи. Вы на 1 сайт можете повесить сколько угодно ip адресов. При каждом заходе на сайт, будет обращение к разным ip, если, к примеру, используется балансер какой-нить, с тем же Round Robin алгоритмом.
2. Не совсем понимаю вопроса. Эти адреса выбирает не jvm, их ресолвит dns сервер.

**UPD:** первый, потому что в реализации так написано. Если посмотреть код метода, то там просто первый элемент берётся из `getAllByName`:

```
public static InetAddress getByName(String host)
     throws UnknownHostException {
     return InetAddress.getAllByName(host)[0];
}
```

Comment: 1. Мммм, хотел написать, что понятно... но спрошу: Что лучше почитать, чтобы все в одной книге? Без понятия, что за "A record", что за "балансер", что за Round Robin...    2. Я имею ввиду, что когда получаю полный список - их 2 шт, а когда беру первый попавшийся, то он какой-то определенный - почему не второй, а именно этот?

Comment: @AlexeyPonochevny по поводу первого не могу ничего посоветовать, сложно конкретную книгу назвать. По поводу второго, я обновил ответ.